# Maximo escalation action fails on CI. Could it be locked?

Tags: python, rest, cron, maximo

Dear Stackoverflow community,

First of, I am not 100% sure if this question should be asked in this stack. If it does not, i'll remove this post.

I have an **ESCALATION** running in ICD (IBM Control Desk / Maximo). This escalation is linked to an **AUTOMATION SCRIPT** through an **ACTION**. The script fires a http call to a REST API and logs the response. The escalation fires the action and thus the script for each found CI. The escalation finds thousands of CI's.

Every now and then there are moments (aproximately one hour) where we get errors:

[image]

During this time, hundreds of CI's are not scanned because the script does not run. I am trying to figure out why these errors occur. Hence the following question:

If a script runs in Maximo, does the script need to finish in order to execute it again on another CI? In other words, if the script is somehow stuck or very slow, could it be a reason why the script won't fire for the other CI's? And in case of a asynchronous execution of the script, how many scripts can fire at the same time?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Escalations in Maximo query the database for the records to process and then proceed to process one of the found records at a time. In your case, it is calling your script to process one CI at a time. So, yes, if your script takes a long time to complete each time it is run, the escalation will still just wait for your script to finish before calling it again for the next record -- creating the effect you are seeing.

Comment: What we see is that the script returns errors during working times. The script has never returned errors while running during the night. A colleague of mine has told me that there are different escalations running during the day (ocasionally)  that access the same CI's. Could these escalations be the cause of this issue? We are now running my script in the weekend (because no other escalations run during that time) to see if the errors occur again. Besides that I will implement some measuring meganism to define the speed between each script execution.